# Concatenate variables inside of a query

Tags: php, mysql

What would be the proper way to concatenate this query?

```
$query2= "SELECT * FROM relationships WHERE user_1= '.$_SESSION['user_id'].'     
AND user_2= '.$user_id.' ";
```

I keep getting this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in C:\xampp\htdocs\beta\profile.php on line 32

Comment: Please do yourself a favor and prevent possible sql-injection by using parameterized queries instead of concatenating strings. By concatenating unescaped strings it is only a matter of time before someone steal, modify or delete all your data. It is a disaster waiting to happen. http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/36866

Answer (score 5):

> What would be the proper way to concatenate this query?

To let your SQL library/client/server do it for you (while escaping special characters for free). Trying to build code by mashing strings together is relatively error prone and involves fiddly combinations of various quote characters that can become hard to maintain.

Use [prepared statements and bound arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/19068) instead.

Comment: and not forgetting the risk of SQL injection attacks when you concatenate strings...

Answer (score 2):

You have an incorrect nesting of single and double quotes.

```
$query2= "SELECT * FROM relationships WHERE user_1= '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "' AND user_2= '" . $user_id . "'";
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. The question is about string concatenation, it is not soliciting opinion on how to access a database.

Comment: @Alnitak: The fact the OP is asking the wrong question doesn't justify downvoting answers that answer it.

Comment: @Eric Exactly this. Downvotes are not warranted here. This answer and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11917758/229044) both correctly answer the question as it is asked. If you don't agree with the method the OP is using, leave a comment on the question, don't downvote correct answers.

Comment: answering the question as written without pointing out the security issue is IMNSVHO irresponsible.

Comment: @meagar and the only reason it is not soliciting that opinion is because the OP doesn't know any better.

Comment: A comment would do more to educate the OP than a downvote on a correct answer.

Comment: If the answerer can demonstrate that he also has enough clue to fix the problem, I'll revert the downvote.  I note that someone has downvoted Quentin's answer, even though it's the best advice the OP will ever get.

Comment: @Alnitak: he probably got downvoted for suggesting prepared statements "without pointing out the security issue" they fix

Answer (score 2):

Either:

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM relationships WHERE user_1='" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'AND user_2='" . $user_id . "'";
```

Or:

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM relationships WHERE user_1='${_SESSION['user_id']}' AND user_2='$user_id'";
```

fixes your syntax error. However, forming queries through concatenation is a bad idea. At the very least, you should `mysql_realescapestring` all the arguments, if not move to using PDO.